# Выбрать поля значение которых равно Null

Tags: java, orm

Использую ORMLite.

Имеется таблица с обращениями [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно создать запрос на выбор незанятых полей (id_authorizSpecialist == Null)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как правильно это сделать?

> where.eq(Handling.AUTHORIZATION_SPECIALIST_HANDLING, null);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте метод [isNull](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/stmt/Where.html#isNull(java.lang.String)):

```
where.isNull(Handling.AUTHORIZATION_SPECIALIST_HANDLING);
```